# How to print a dict of Altair's default configuration

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to print a dictionary (or a list) of `Altair`'s default configuration.
In the module documentation I found an object named `altair.Config()` that I thought would contain the default configuration of Altair. I tried the following:

```
import altair as alt
conf = alt.Config()
print(conf.to_dict())
```

but it just prints an empty dictionary.

How can I print the default configuration fo Altair? specifically, I'd like to know the name of the default font (which I couldn't find in the documentation either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no font default defined in Altair. Altair's default settings are found within its default theme:

```
>>> import altair as alt
>>> theme = alt.themes.get()
>>> theme()
{'config': {'view': {'continuousHeight': 300, 'continuousWidth': 400}}}
```

Everything else is defined by Vega-Lite or Vega when the chart is rendered.